# Portal to Jurassic like world

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

Story was about a group of teens, one of which is cleaning out his grandfathers shed and finds a portal in the back.
His name was Charlie if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this might be Wildside, by Steven Gould.

The characters are teens, and the main character, Charlie (which fits with your recollections) has discovered a portal to a parallel world in his Uncle's barn.  Because the world is one in which humanity hasn't evolved, there are extinct species alive and so might qualify as "Jurassic Like" (although no actual dinosaurs that I recall, just ones where man caused the extinction).